# How to address Null Pointers in Java error in ColdFusion 9?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9.1.0.

I am working on part of a site that someone else developed a while back. That someone is gone and there is no documentation.  I can access the CF Administrator, but I can't find anything that helps me with a specific problem.

In the code below, a Java object is created (auth) and then in the next line, the object is referenced.  Two variables are passed to the method (runTransaction), the properties file (VARIABLES.PropsFile) and the XML (VARIABLES.MyXML).

```
<cfobject action="create" type="Java" class="CyberSource" name="auth">
<cfset VARIABLES.ResponseString = auth.runTransaction(VARIABLES.PropsFile,VARIABLES.MyXML)>
```

The object is successfully created. I know this because when I change the class of the object, it blows up! When I change it back to "CyberSource", it works.

I know that the properties file exists. I know that the XML exists.

The error I get is this:

```
The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code.

Null Pointers are another name for undefined values.

The error occurred in D:/inetpub/wwwroot/Watkins_OE-DEV/Test.cfm: line 63

61 : <!--- CREATE JAVA OBJECT --->
62 : <cfobject action="create" type="Java" class="CyberSource" name="auth">
63 : <cfset VARIABLES.ResponseString = auth.runTransaction(VARIABLES.PropsFile,VARIABLES.MyXML)>
```

Can you provide me with any clues as to what this error really means and where I might look next?

**EDIT:**

I can't pinpoint what my problem WAS, but I went about solving it a different way. I found a file that WAS working and slowly rebuilt it, testing it 100 times along the way.

Many thanks for the tips and hints!

Comment: What do `<cfdump var="#PropsFile#">` and `<cfdump var="#MyXML#">` give? Do they exist and look sensible?

Comment: Yes, they exist and look great.  I know the props file exists because I can see it and I used fileExists() to test for its existence. The XML is created by me on the page. I can output it and read it just fine.

Comment: So the NullPointerException occurs *within* `runTransaction()`, and there is not a whole lot you can do from ColdFusion (apart from `<cftry>/<cfcatch>`, obviously). You must debug that Java class. Maybe it expects a certain XML node to be there and uses it without checking for it?

Comment: Does the Java Class have to be "registered" in CF Administrator via the Extensions tool?  If so, it's not there.

Comment: No, it just has to be in the class path (besides, it would throw a class not found exception if that was the problem). You can see all the jars that CF has loaded in the CF admin server summary.

Comment: IIRC I also had to manually add the paths to jvm.config. It did not work without that step. See CF instructions [here](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/downloads/cybersource_developer_kits/Java/All_Platforms/readme)

Comment: @Leigh Dropping the jar in the class path and restarting the server ought to be enough. Would also not blow up with a NullPointerException if it could not find the class, or would it?

Comment: @Tomalak - I agree, normally yes. But I definitely remember having issues with cybersource until adding the four jar paths to jvm.config. The NPE may be indicating a problem loading or initializing the class, rather than not being able to find it at all. I would look further down the stack trace for the root cause.

Comment: What does <cfdump var="#auth#"> show you?

Comment: Actually I may have misread the question. It thought it was brand *new* code, rather than an existing app.

Comment: Leigh, the document pointed me to was a great help. I wish you were running the CyberSource customer service program!

Comment: @Erik - Glad it helped. I was pleasantly surprised to find *any* CF specific information in their documentation ;) Though it may be a little outdated. I remember something about excluding log4j and xalan to avoid conflicts with CF's built jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, wrap your auth.runTransaction() with a try/catch.

The following snippet comes from the samples included with the CyberSource java api:

```
<!--- Change this to point to your property file --->
<cfset propsFile = "full_path_to/coldfusion/samples/cybs.properties">

<!--- Change this to point to your request file --->
<cffile action="Read" file="full_path_to/coldfusion/samples/xml/request.xml" variable="requestString">

<cfobject action="create" type="Java" class="CyberSource" name="auth">
<cfxml variable="requestDoc">
    <cfoutput>#requestString#</cfoutput>
</cfxml>
<cfdump label="Request" var="#requestDoc#">

<cftry>

<!--- make the call --->
<cfset responseString = auth.runTransaction(propsFile,requestString)>

<!--- cast the response to xml --->
<cfxml variable="responseDoc">
<cfoutput>#responseString#</cfoutput>
</cfxml>
<cfdump label="Response" var="#responseDoc#">

<!--- exception handling --->
<cfcatch type="com.cybersource.ws.client.ClientException">
    <cfoutput><b>Exception Message:</b> #cfcatch.message#</cfoutput><br><br>
    <cfdump label="com.cybersource.ws.client.ClientException" var=#cfcatch#>
</cfcatch>

<cfcatch type="com.cybersource.ws.client.FaultException">
    <cfoutput><b>Exception Message:</b> #cfcatch.message#</cfoutput><br><br>
    <cfdump label="com.cybersource.ws.client.FaultException" var=#cfcatch#>
</cfcatch>

</cftry>
```

There are some coldfusion samples inside the All Platforms Java zip downloadable here:

http://apps.cybersource.com/cgi-bin/pages/dev_kits.cgi?kit=Java/All_Platforms